# No data available for encoding 1252 - Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am using Xamarin to develop an Android app, while trying to convert text to `byte[]` I get the following error:

> no data is available for encoding 1252

My code:

```
byte[] mybyteA= Portable.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mystring);

Mono.Security.Cryptography.SHA224Managed sha22 = new _Mono.Security.Cryptography.SHA224Managed();
byte[] hash = sha22.ComputeHash(mybyteA);
```

Comment: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=39237

Comment: Is this your actual code? The only part that deals with encodings is the first line, and it uses UTF-8, not cp1252... which line throws the exception exactly?

Comment: Which line is causing the error? Are you sure you're supposed to use anything in the `_Mono` namespace?

Comment: I should add this works in debugging but fails in release on  the first line (actual encoding  line)

Comment: I get the same error even if i use the system.security. the error is on the first line.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [Western Code page (1252)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) isn't being bundled into your final IPA/APK.

For iOS projects, include it by checking `west` under **Project Properties** -> **iOS Build** -> **Internationalization**:

[image]

For Android projects, include it by checking `west` under **Project Properties** -> **Android Build** -> **Linker** -> **Internationalization**:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

In Visual Studio, you must go to the properties window of each project:

**iOS**

You must scroll down until 'west'

[image]

**Android**
[image]