# Release build of GetEncoding("ISO-8859-8") give "Encoding 28598 data could not be found" error

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Why does this line
`GetEncoding("ISO-8859-8").GetBytes(text);` raise this exception: `Encoding 28598 data could not be found. Make sure you have correct international codeset assembly installed and enabled.`

But in **release build** only?? (Xamarin Forms running the Android build).

And how can I work around it. It is code based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331279/how-to-change-diacritic-characters-to-non-diacritic-ones/3314310#3314310), and here is my function (which is in a PCL library):

```
    public static string RemoveDiacritics(this string text)
    {
        if (text == null)
            return string.Empty;

        byte[] tempBytes;
        tempBytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-8").GetBytes(text);
        string asciiStr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tempBytes, 0, tempBytes.Length);

        return asciiStr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Silly question, but is it possible that the Debug version is using a local copy of the DLL?

Comment: On what platform does it fail? I just tried with VS2015 on Windows 7 (PCL in C#, console project to use it in VB) and got no error.

Comment: Ah yes - important question! Android.

Comment: Have you seen [No data available for encoding 1252 - Xamarin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37780366/1115360)?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue selecting **Mideast** under Project Properties:
Project Properties -> Android Options -> Additional supported encodings: "Mideast"

[image: View Image]

Comment: Please explain the steps in writing.