# Android C# local network access

Tags: c#, android

I'm working on an android app to be deployed in a warehouse, and I'm having issues accessing the SQL database on the `192.168.8.*` network. It works fine in debug, but when I come to deploying it in the release it is unable to make the connection.

As it's all internal I'm directly running queries on the SQL as opposed to creating a service layer.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

My connection string is like so

```
Server={0};Database=Database;User Id={1};Password={2};Connection Timeout=10;
```

Code:

```
  public static string ReturnString(string query, string expectedDataType = 
  "STRING")
    {
        SqlConnection connection = null;
        try
        {
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
            {
                //open connection
                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = query;

                var result = command.ExecuteScalar();

                //close connection
                connection.Close();
                //see if there is a table to return
                if (expectedDataType == "INT" && (result == System.DBNull.Value || result == null))
                {
                    return "0";
                }
                if (result != "" && (result != null  && result != System.DBNull.Value))
                {
                    return result.ToString();
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            #region connection error
            Console.Write("ERROR IS HERE: " + exception);
            #endregion
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: we need to see your code to help you.

Comment: did you try to save the exception logs somewhere , file  maybe ?  i . would go for a crash analytics service  , but i don't know if that's suitable for your case .

Comment: The firewall might be blocking the API request from Android. Please try disabling the firewall and check if it works or not.

Comment: @Legion have added the method, although the opening, has gone out of the code block

 all firewalls are turned off in the test environment :/

Comment: try to  display  the exception's message in a  dialog or a toast, just to give you an idea on what's going on

Comment: @FarabiAbdelwahed 
System.NotSupportException: Encoding 1252 data could not be found. Make sure you have correct international codeset assembly installed and enabled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No data available for encoding 1252 - Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779459/no-data-available-for-encoding-1252-xamarin)